# PHP exec() curl Returns errno 18 (CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE )

Tags: php, shell, curl, exec

When I use the shell command `curl` from PHP to  grab a zip format file, it returns errno 18.

I retried 3 times, it always returns errno 18.

Code:

```
    $shell = "curl \"{$url}\" -k -o {$localfile} "; 

    exec($shell, $outPut, $rVal);
```

The return value, `$rVal`, always equals 18 (`CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE`).

Someone said `CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE` means that the transfer was aborted before the full contents arrived.

I wonder if it should return errno 28 instead [Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.]?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can format your code indenting it 4 spaces from the left, with a blank before the beginning of the code block. See [the advanced formatting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more information. You can also put `backticks` around short pieces of code to format them as code with fixed-width font.

Comment: Why would it say timeout if it is a partial transfer? Also, using -v may help you figure out exactly what happens.